# Authenticate credentials received from facebook on my own REST API

Tags: android, api, oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

Me and my team are working on a native mobile social network for Android that allows users to login using Facebook. Ive managed to implement the Facebook SDK for Android, but im struggling to figure out how to properly/securely authenticate a user who logs in using facebook with the credentials received from Facebook alone. Currently here is how my system goes:

Step 1.From the Android client the user presses login with Facebook and grants permissions to my app.

Step 2. Upon the user granting our permissions Facebook sends us a response that includes the users fb user id, email and a token ( among other info if this is the first time the user has logged in using facebook)

Step 3. Info is sent up to our API for authentication

**and this is where im a bit unclear....How can I validate the facebook credentials on my server?**

As of now im just checking my db for a existing user with the fb_uid and fb_email received, but anyone can get anyones fb_uid and it not that much harder to find the email they used to sign up for facebook which means someone hypothetically could easily hack into another users account with a faked http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `access_token`, if valid, will allow you to access some of the user Facebook data that your app has requested permission to access.  One way to validate that the credentials you are receiving are correct is to use that `access_token` to query Facebook.

For example, [this page suggests how to open up the `access_token` properties](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/) using a `GET` call:

```
GET graph.facebook.com/debug_token?
 input_token={token-to-inspect}
 &access_token={app-token-or-admin-token}
```

Which then returns:

```
{
    "data": {
        "app_id": 138483919580948, 
        "application": "Social Cafe", 
        "expires_at": 1352419328, 
        "is_valid": true, 
        "issued_at": 1347235328, 
        "metadata": {
            "sso": "iphone-safari"
        }, 
        "scopes": [
            "email", 
            "publish_actions"
        ], 
        "user_id": 1207059
    }
}
```

Comment: You are the boss apple sauce my friend . Thank you much sir!

Comment: @Peter - have you used this approach in production? how is it in terms of performance? I imagine it would be costly to do this for every API request.

Comment: @jramoyo: What I describe above is only really needed if you error out (try to use permissions that you don't have).  So, yes, I've used it in "production" but only for error processing if the access token doesn't do what we want to do. It is certainly not needed for all (any?) API requests (though the access token is, for non-public information).

Comment: Then how on earth do u know a incoming fb login request is not being faked? How hard is it to get a users fb uid and email? if you dont do a token check every time you receive a fb login request dont you make your app vulnerable to account hacks ?

Comment: @ChuckKelly: I don't understand your question as it doesn't make sense.  The FB login request handshake happens at the start, which generates a short-term access token. That access token is used for further API calls. So, of course there is a token check every time, what I was saying is that the login handshake (that generates the access token) doesn't happen every API call.

Comment: android app log's in with fb, with the fb credentials it also logs into my api on my server....easily fakeable, whats not to get unless u havent worked with a api before?

Comment: @ChuckKelly: Ah, I see, I thought you were saying that the calls to FB had to be authenticated every time.  Well, if your API only depends on  the FB token to authenticate a user... then of course it can be faked!